# Parsing through XML using JQuery, possibly use JSON instead of XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-parsing

I've got a pretty good foundation laid but I just can't seem to get it to work properly.

**Demo Here:**  [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/alexcory/8uNgZ/1/)

Basically it wouldn't run on localhost and when I put it into JSFiddle it keeps telling me:

```
Error 404
We're truly sorry, but there is no such page.
```

Not sure if it's because I don't have it setup right on JSFiddle? Probably not though.

Also, would it be easier to use `JSON`? I'd love to learn how to do it with JSON. Also, I've never tried this with jQuery before so any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: in your fiddle you forgot to include jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uaRJ8/1/ - still your ajax request is in violation of [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: You can't use `<?php ?>` in jsFiddle. Replace that with some sample data.

Comment: Try console of your browser to investigate the fault. Using Chrome i see «XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx/GetCityForecastByZIP?zip=. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access. »  
You are trying to do cross-domain query. It is not allowed! Learn more abour #crossdomain requests

Comment: Will the php screw it up even though it's commented out?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uNgZ/2/).

Your fiddle was incorrectly setup. You forgot to choose jQuery on the left top of the jsfiddle's site. See Screenshot

[image: jsfiddle jquery]

In addition, you will not able to use xml across domain. It is violate browser security. I recommend you to use [jsonp](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and you may need to specify `application/json` in your header..

```
 <?php header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');?>
```

Something similar with that. Let me know if you stumble with other issue.